# Как передать строку подключения для Migration в Entity Framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Есть проект  типа .NETStandart 2.0 "DAL.EFcore". Он обеспечивает SQL хранилище данных путем реализации абстрактного репозиотория.
Т.е. только в этом проекте есть зависимость от EFCore.
Контекст данных зависит от строки подключения.

```
public sealed class Context : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connString;


    #region Reps

    public DbSet<EfStation> EfStations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EfRoute> EfRoutes { get; set; }

    #endregion



    public Context(string connString)
    {
        _connString = connString;

        //Отключение Tracking для всего контекста
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new EfRouteConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}


//В проекте WebApi репозиторий получает зависимость

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        //TODO: connString брать из настрек
        var connString = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MarkSimanDB;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        services.AddTransient<IStationRepository>(s => new EfStationsRepository(connString));
    }
```

Поскольку нет конструктора по умолчанию, то миграция не выполняется.
Расскажите как выполнить миграцию если конструктор контекста не базовый.

Comment: Что означает "выполнить миграцию"? Выполнить в консоли Nuget? Тогда передавайте конн строку, например "Update-Database  -ConnectionStringName MyConStr" вместо "Update-Database" Но я бы добавил ещё один конструктор public Context(): base("DefaultConnection") и не морочился бы.

Comment: Так и сделал с конструктором)), для разработки удобно.

Comment: Я когда-то игрался с тем, чтобы полностью отвязывать приложение от EF, возможно поможет вот [такая статья](http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/entityframework-removing-dependency-from-web-application) и [репозиторий](https://github.com/djhmateer/3Commerce) от книги Марка Симана "DI CSharp" - в итоге помню, что были проблемы с конфигом приложения, с тем, что нужно копировать dll (ссылок никаких ведь нету!) и что-то ещё.

Comment: А package manager console можно вызывать отдельно от Visual studio и выполнять миграции?

Comment: Читал эту книгу,

Comment: А вот еще вопрос из моих фантазий)). хочу сделать микросервис с CRUD операциями к бд, где наружу торчит стандартный REST api. Другие сервисы или UI приложения рабоают с этим интерфейсом. Размещать его придется в контейнере (Docker). Если БД находится в контейнере, то как из хост ОС вообще работать с БД? Т.е. хотелось бы и отладку вести в контейнере, а не отлаживать локально и потом создавать новый образ с новой бд.

Comment: Посмотрите код в ответе (не стал в комментариях, чтобы было наглядно видно), вам что-то типа нужно? Или в чём проблема? Скажем, вам нужно инстанцировать Context через активатор Activator.CreateInstance, дав на конструктор коннстроку?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72279/discussion-between-a-k-and-aldmi).